# Fondo en la página

Tags: visual-studio, background, fondo, vscode-live-server, winrar

Estoy empezando a programar y creo que es un error bastante básico, utilizo visual studio, cuando quiero poner un fondo para la página me sale perfecto si lo abro desde la extensión del live server. Pero cuando intento abrir el index desde una carpeta rar me sale un fondo totalmente blanco, alguien sabe que puede ser?

Comment: Tu pregunta necesita aclaración. ¿Estás usando Visual Studio o visual Studio Code? ¿Qué estás programando? ¿En qué lenguaje? ¿Cuáles son los pasos que sigues para abrir el index de un rar?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.